# Custom Role in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-rbac

Can i create a Custom role or edit existing role in Azure Synapse, where

1. i can provide only SELECT query access using Built-in serverless Pool and
2. Pipelines access should be restricted

Ideally i'm looking for a role who can only read SQL & Lake data, query it using different technologies (SQL, Spark) and should not have access to anything else

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create the External Table on the required using the Database Scoped Credential and first GRANT REFERENCES and then `SELECT` permission to the External Table for SQL user. Follow the below steps:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SampleIdentity
WITH IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity'
GO
```

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [DataLakeStorage] WITH (LOCATION = N'https://theorders.dfs.core.windows.net/', CREDENTIAL =  SampleIdentity)
GO
```

Caller must have one of the following permissions to execute OPENROWSET function:

- One of the permissions to execute OPENROWSET:

  - `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` enables login to execute `OPENROWSET` function.
  - `ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS` enables database scoped user to execute OPENROWSET function.
- `REFERENCES DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL` to the credential that is referenced in EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE.

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL::[SampleIdentity] TO [SQLUser];
GO
```

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[DimProductexternal]
( ProductKey int, ProductLabel nvarchar, ProductName nvarchar )
WITH
(
LOCATION='/DimProduct/year=*/month=*' ,
DATA_SOURCE = AzureDataLakeStore ,
FILE_FORMAT = TextFileFormat
) ;
```

You can now Grant `SELECT` permission to the user for external table.

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[DimProductexternal] TO [SQLUser]
GO
```

To restrict the access to the resource in Synapse, you can assign **ROLE BASED ACEESS CONTROL (RBAC)**

To restrict run/cancel pipelines access in Synapse workspace you can assign `Synapse Monitoring Operator` role using the RBAC in synapse. Refer [Synapse RBAC roles and the actions they permit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-synapse-rbac-roles#synapse-rbac-roles-and-the-actions-they-permit) for more details.